# Is the memory allocated for struct members continguous? What if a struct member is an array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct

In C/C++ suppose  I define a simple struct named `test` as follows.

```
struct test
{
   double height;
   int    age;
   char   gender;
}
```

For a specific instance of this struct  say `test A` are `A.height, A.age, A.gender` contiguous
in memory?

More generally, how do the layouts in memory for a Structure of Arrays and an Array of structures look like? A picture would be really helpful.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

They will not necessarily be contiguous in memory. This is due to [struct padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

However, in your particular case, it may very well be contiguous. But if you changed the order to something like this:

```
struct test
{
    char   gender;
    int    age;
    double height;
}
```

then they most likely will not be. However, in your particular case, you will still likely get padding after `gender`, to realign the struct to 8 bytes.

---

The difference between SoA (**Struct of Arrays**) and AoS (**Array of Structs**) would be like this:

**SoA:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| double | double | double | *pad* | int | int | int | *pad* | char | char | char |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**AoS:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| double | int | char | *pad* | double | int | char | *pad* | double | int | char |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that AoS pads within each struct. While SoA pads between the arrays.

**These have the following trade-offs:**

1. **AoS** tends to be more readable to the programmer as each "object" is kept together.
2. **AoS** may have better cache locality if all the members of the struct are accessed together.
3. **SoA** could potentially be more efficient since grouping same datatypes together sometimes exposes vectorization.
4. In many cases **SoA** uses less memory because padding is only between arrays rather than between every struct.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what are those SoA and AoS you are explaining without defining them?

Comment: Ah, good point. I saw that the OP already defined them, but I didn't realize that the abbreviations AoS and SoA weren't mentioned. (AoS = Array of Structs, SoA = Structure of Arrays)

Comment: I'd add many compilers support removing padding with ` #pragma pack(1)`.  Padding is there for good reason. Speed / Memory trade-offs involved.

Comment: @Mysticial: Hello , I got into this and I wanted to ask you if you can.If I had a structure " struct { 

  int v;
  int arr[ 5 ]; 
 
} " , would I have padding or not?Because both are int's.Thanks!

Comment: @George Probably not for any system that exists today.

Comment: I am typically making a decision between readability and vectorization.

Comment: The SoA almsot certainly has no padding based on how you've presented it i.e arraof doubles first, then ints and finally chars.

Answer (score 17):

The individual fields are contiguous in the sense that there will be no other variables stored in-between them.  They are also guaranteed to be stored in the order that you declared.  But the compiler is free to insert padding in-between the individual fields to align things to word boundaries, for instance.  So the following:

```
struct test
{
    double height;
    char   gender;
    int    age;
};
```

may look like this in memory:

```
         +7  +6  +5  +4  +3  +2  +1  +0
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
0x0000  |            height             |
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
0x0008  |      age      |           |gen|
        +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

As for the difference between SoA and AoS, they're laid out exactly as you might imagine.

Answer (score -1):

Other than the standard disclaimer of "it depends on your platform, compiler, blahblahblah"... yes, `height`, `age`, and `gender` will be contiguous in memory with no padding in between:

`height|age|gender`

However, if you have an array of `test`, each array element will have padding in between them after each's `gender` so that the next element's `height` is properly aligned.

`|height0|age0|gender0|padding0|height1|age1|gender1|padding1|...`

If your goal is to use the least amount of memory possible, then you should go with "structure of arrays" since it uses no padding.

`|height0|height1|...`

`|age0|age1|...`

`|gender0|gender1|...`