# Memory layout of C struct

Tags: c, struct

Can I be sure that the following code will work on all platforms?

```
struct example{
  int a;
  int b;
} example;

*((int*)(((void*)&example) + sizeof(int))) = 33;
```

This should change the value of (b) inside (example) to 33.

Comment: No, because padding might exist, not to mention this violates aliasing rules. Why do you think you want to do this? Also, how would this even compile? `33` cannot be assigned to a `struct example`, which is what your pointer points to - albeit, by the time you've added `sizeof(int) * sizeof(example)` bytes to it as you do here, not a valid/dereferenceable one.

Comment: padding does not matter in this example

Comment: @P__J__ I wrote that before I realised the pointer being added has the wrong type/increment. That part of the comment still applies, even if the type was correct.

Comment: Is there a way arround padding? like a compiler flag

Comment: Yes, but it won't save you here, and nor should it. Again, why do you think this is the kind of code you should be writing? What problem are you trying to solve? There must be a better way.

Comment: I was curious if this would work

Comment: I'm curious why you would want it to!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Layout in memory of a struct. struct of arrays  and array of structs in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377667/layout-in-memory-of-a-struct-struct-of-arrays-and-array-of-structs-in-c-c)

Comment: Assuming that you want to access the next `int` in the struct through pointer arithmetic, then there is no formal guarantee that there's no padding in between. In practice though, it is very likely to work, portably, if the struct has the minimal alignment requirement of an `int` as in this case.

Answer (score 5):

It will not for sure.

`&example + sizeof(int)` this operation moves the pointer `sizeof(int) * sizeof(example)` bytes ahead.

And this line will not compile at all

`*(&example + sizeof(int)) = 33;`

To know the offset of the particular field in the **struct** or **union** use `offsetof`

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/offsetof.3.html

Comment: I have updated the code to make that what I want

Comment: @Daniel Your update doesn't make any sense. You just de-reference the first int object then add its value together with the size of an int.

Comment: `void *` arthmetics is the compiler **extension** - so it is not poirtable as well