# Is it legal to access class members as an array?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Consider this code:

```
struct Point {
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;

  void setByIndex(int i, double value) {
      (&x)[i] = value;
  }
};
```

The `setByIndex()` function works and [does what I want](https://godbolt.org/z/8MPYc8). But can I be sure this is not a UB (when called with a proper `i`)? Could you please provide references to the standard with the explanation?

Comment: I guess it is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8377667/10553341

Comment: `Is it legal to access class members as an array?` No, that's undefiend behavior. `can I be sure this is not a UB` You can be sure this is UB. `Could you please provide references to the standard with the explanation?` The `Is it legal to index into a struct?` duplicate has them all, [expr/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4) would the most important.

Comment: You are looking for the location (address) of an element of a structure.  One of the issues is that the compiler can add padding between elements of a structure (for example, for alignment purposes).  Another issue is that elements of a structure can be of different types; which makes the pointer value calculation difficult.  When you have a pointer to an int, incrementing and (pointer math) is based on units of "int" size.  What happens when you have int as one element and a struct as the next?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I mean this specific example. I already understood this is UB. I wonder though, does it change if I add `#pragma pack` to ensure there is no padding?

Comment: If you want to access the elements like an array, use `std::vector`, not `struct` or place them into a `vector` inside the struct.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews well, with all due respect, this is a bragging, not an answer :)

Comment: @Mikhail: I'm not bragging.  Your struct has 3 fields with identical types in succession.  This fits the pattern of an array or a vector.