# Is it legal to cast a struct to an integer if it has no padding?

Tags: c

```
struct test {
 char a, b, c, d;
};

int main(){
 
 struct test t = {1,2,3,4};
 int d = *(int*)&t;
 assert(d == 67305985);

 return 0;
}
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8377679/14940626) mentions that struct members are contiguous in the sense that there will be no other variables stored in-between them. It also says that they are guaranteed to be stored in the order they are declared.

I'm using 1 byte characters so there shouldn't be any need for padding in between them. Putting all this together, does this mean my code above is legal on *little endian* platforms with no undefined behaviour? (assert will fail on big endian).

Comment: What about alignment?

Comment: padding is done for alignment. chars don't need alignment.

Comment: This struct doesn't need alignment, but an `int` might need it. `&t` might not be suitably aligned for an `int`. In any case this is undefined behavior, you should `memcpy` instead.

Comment: why is it UB? any reference?

Comment: Use a `union`. _

Comment: Because of a [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/2752075) violation.

Comment: In case of structs, it is guaranteed to be aligned ("fundamental alignment"), as is the first element. So this is only a matter of a so-called strict pointer aliasing violation. Which in turn is a FAQ.

Comment: @Lundin: C 2018 2 defines a *fundamental alignment* to be “a valid alignment less than or equal to `_Alignof (max_align_t)`.” It also requires structures without members having stricter alignment requirements to have a fundamental alignment requirement. This means any such structure must have an alignment requirement less than or equal to `_Alignof (max_align_t)`, not that it must have an alignment requirement that is at least `_Alignof (max_align_t)`. This is evident from the fact that it gives the same requirement for `char` (a basic type), which obviously has alignment requirement 1.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But in practice it means that each struct will likely be aligned at a suitable word basis for the CPU.

Comment: @Lundin: No, it does not. That paragraph is merely saying alignments for “ordinary” objects (ones not involving extended types or requested alignments) will have alignement requirements less than or equal to that of `max_align_t`. It in no way suggests they should have alignment requirements corresponding to a processor word. GCC and Clang both report the structure in the question has an alignment requirement of one byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(int *) &t` is not defined if `t` is not aligned as required for an `int`, per C 2018 6.3.2.3 7:

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined…

If it is correctly, aligned, `* (int *) &t` attempts to access it using an lvalue expression of type `int`. This is not defined, per C 2018 6.5 7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type.

For an object of type `struct test`, `int` is not any of the above listed types, so the “shall” requirement is violated. Violating a “shall” requirement renders the behavior not defined by the C standard, per C 2018 4 2:

> If a “shall” or “shall not” requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined…

> Is it legal to cast a struct to an integer if it has no padding?

It is legal in the sense the C standard does not prohibit it. However, the standard does not define the behavior.

Comment: so breaks the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: @Dan: It breaks C 2018 6.5 7. Some people call that the strict aliasing rule. It is C 2018 6.5 7.

Comment: As @Lundin points out in a comment, since C14 every struct has alignment as least as strict as `max_align_t`, so alignment isn't an issue after all.

Comment: @aschepler: The C standard (up to and including 2018) does not require structures to have alignment as strict as `max_align_t`. The C standard defines a *fundamental alignment* (not *the* fundamental alignment) to be a valid alignment **less than or equal to** `_Alignof (max_align_t)`. C 2018 6.2.8 2 specifies that structures whose elements all have fundamental alignment requirements shall have a fundamental alignment. That means it is saying such structures may have **at most** the alignment requirement of `max_align_t`, not that they have **at least** that alignment requirement.

Comment: @aschepler: With GCC 13.2 and Clang 17.0.1, using `-std=c18`, `printf("%zu\n", _Alignof (struct test { char a, b, c, d; }));` prints “1”.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the "fundamental alignment" wording. And this does make more sense - it would be strange if even `struct S { char c; };` had large alignment and therefore size!